# T-SQL : how to split order detail quantities out into separate rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have following order detail query

```
 OrderId    item          Quantity
 ----------------------------------
 3402323    Item1         3
 3402323    Item2         1
 3402324    Item1         2
```

And the results I need are

```
 OrderId    item          Quantity
 ----------------------------------
 3402323-1  Item1         1
 3402323-2  Item1         1
 3402323-3  Item1         1
 3402323-4  Item2         1
 3402324-1  Item1         1
 3402324-2  Item1         1
```

Is there a way to do this without using a temp table and populating it with a cursor?

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use a Tally. These are far faster than a rCTE, especially if (in this scenario) you have large values for `Quantity`, and can't suffer from hitting the max recursion problem, as they aren't recursive.

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(3402323,'Item1',3),
                (3402323,'Item2',1),
                (3402324,'Item1',2))V(OrderID,Item,Quantity)),
N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(Quantity) FROM YourTable)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --1000 rows
SELECT CONCAT(YT.OrderID,'-',T.I) AS OrderID,
       YT.Item,
       1 AS Quantity
FROM YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON YT.Quantity >= T.I;
```

Comment: Interesting.  How would the query look if I wanted to select from my order details table were OrderID in (3402323,3402324)

Comment: You'd use a `WHERE` @DekeDarsey, just like normal.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive subquery:

```
with cte as (
      select orderid, item, quantity, 1 as n
      from t
      union all
      select orderid, item, quantity, n + 1
      from cte
      where n < quantity
     )
select orderid, item, 1 as quantity
from cte;
```

If your quantities exceed 100, then you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2016 or later you can utilize the STRING_SPLIT function and the REPLICATE function to achieve the result you are looking for. The REPLICATE function can be used to create a comma delimited string that repeats N number of times (this will be your quantity). The STRING_SPLIT function can be used to split the string into N number of records you can join on.
The following example shows how this would work with your data.

```
DECLARE @orders TABLE
(
    OrderId     VARCHAR(50)
    ,Item       VARCHAR(50)
    ,Quantity   INT
)

INSERT INTO @orders
SELECT 3402323    ,'Item1',   3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3402323    ,'Item2',   1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3402324    ,'Item1',   2

SELECT
     OrderId = O.OrderId + '-' + CAST( (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY O.OrderId ORDER BY O.Item, OE.RepeatId) ) AS VARCHAR(50) )
    ,O.Item
    ,Quantity = 1
FROM
    @orders O
CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT RepeatId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [value])
        FROM
            STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE ( ',', O.Quantity - 1), ',')
    ) OE
```